# internal mechanism of hazelcast to store object with in object?

Tags: hazelcast

how hazelcast deals with object with in object. let me give you an example,

```
class Students{
String name, rollNumber;
Enrollments enrolments[];
 // some methods

}

class Enrollments {
   String id, subjectName;
 // some methods and fields

}
```

as you see, Students class holds an array/list of enrollment objects. My question is, how hazelcast deals with objects in side object(in respect to memory)? what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It serializes it. Obviously you need to implement Serializable for both classes at the very least. Avoid circular dependencies and generally complex hierarchies. Otherwise as long as all member classes and their members are serializable, you are fine.

Standard Java serialization memory footprint is pretty bad, so if you have complex structures, consider DataSerializable or Portable.